# AVFoundationでのBGMの再生について(Swift)

Tags: swift

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation

class ViewController: UIViewController, AVAudioPlayerDelegate {
    var audioPlayer:AVAudioPlayer!
    @IBOutlet var button:UIButton!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let audioPath = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("sample", ofType: "mp3")!)
        //audioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL:audioPath)
        audioPlayer.delegate = self
        audioPlayer.prepareToPlay()

    }

    @IBAction func buttonTapped(sender : AnyObject) {
        if ( audioPlayer.playing ){
            audioPlayer.stop()
            button.setTitle("Stop", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
        }
        else{
            audioPlayer.play()
            button.setTitle("Play", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
        }
    }
}
```

コメントアウトの部分で「Call can throw, but it is not marked with 'try' and the error is not handled」というエラーが出てしまいます。どなたか解決方法をお教えください。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Swift 2より`try`構文によるエラー処理が導入され、標準のAPIは（エラーの起こる可能性のあるメソッド呼び出しは）その方式でエラー処理をしなければならないように変更されました。

```
do {
    audioPlayer = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL:audioPath)
} catch let error {
    // ここでエラー処理をする
}
```

エラー処理をきちんとするなら上記のように `do〜try〜catch`を使ってエラーを捕捉します。

エラー処理をしない（エラーが起こったときはクラッシュさせる、あるいはオブジェクトが`nil`になる）で良い場合は、下記のように`try!`や`try?`を利用すると、（エラーを捕捉しないので）`do〜catch`ブロックは不要になります。

下記はエラーのときにクラッシュします。

```
audioPlayer = try! AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL:audioPath)
```

次のように書くと、エラーが起こったときは`audioPlayer`変数は`nil`になります。

```
audioPlayer = try? AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL:audioPath)
```